# AngularJS 2 ZoneAwarePromise instead a boolean value

Tags: angular

I have a base class in AngularJS 2 for restClient to call data from API with this method:

```
public getInfoDataBooleanRequest(url: string): InfoDataBoolean {
  return this.http.get(this.urlApiPrefix + url, this.createRequestOptions())
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => <InfoDataBoolean>response.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

where InfoDataBoolean is a class with two properties:

```
export class InfoDataBoolean {
    public data: boolean;
    public error: string;
}
```

I have another class where I called my service method.
This call is inside a method where I want to return the data from InfoDataBoolean, not the class InfoDataBoolean like this.

```
public isLogged(): boolean {
   return this.getInfoDataBooleanRequest('islogged').then(x => {
      let result: InfoDataBoolean = x;

      if(result.error !== "1") {
        console.log('Success is failed');
        return false;
      }

      return result.data;
   });
}
```

The output of `console.log(isLogged())`:

> ZoneAwarePromise {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array[0]}

But I want to return `true` or `false` from my method `isLogged()`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't forget that your `isLogged` method is asynchronous and return a promise. To get the result you need to register a callback on it with the `then` method:

```
console.log(isLogged());
isLogged().then(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

In your case, you display the promise and the returned result when it will be resolved...